# Use of each and every

Tags: grammar, pronouns

> Practically **every** part of the banana tree is used by man.

I think this sentence is correct but my grammar book say there should be **each** instead of **every**. I know we can't use every as a pronoun but in above sentence **every part** used as a single unit. 
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: *Each* would make your sentence significantly worse, while *every* is fine.  The book is wrong if that's what it says.

Comment: This Google Ngram result confirms your (and my) intuition: http://goo.gl/MRYYUP

Comment: This might be more telling in this situation: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=practically+every+part%2Cpractically+each+part%2Calmost+every+part%2Calmost+each+part&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpractically%20every%20part%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calmost%20every%20part%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True. But then, if we want to talk about the banana tree's part individually (though all), we use *each* and not *every*.

[BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv110.shtml) clarifies it-

> We tend to use each if we are thinking about members of a group individually, and every if we are thinking of them in total.

Compare the following:

> We gave **each child** who came to the party a present. We handed them out *one by one*. 
>  We gave **every child** who came to the party a present We gave **them all** a present.

---

Found *the exact phrase* from the book [Hawaiian Heritage Plants](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=6DjyNkRevskC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=%22each%20part%20of%20the%20banana%22&source=bl&ots=iyiuU7zAuM&sig=oh3LVpB5sW9VxOFhdEd_fxF650o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kpmJVLDhGZSpuQSUloBg&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22each%20part%20of%20the%20banana%22&f=false) where it says ***each part*** is usable one or the other way.

Comment: Note that *each* doesn't permit modification by *practically*, while *every* does.  (CGEL p.379)

Comment: @snailboat Yes, I'm aware of that. I have read posts on other English forums. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Then why did you not bother telling the OP the relevant portion of the answer, if you already knew?  This answer fails to address the example in question.

Comment: @snailboat No! In fact the first sentence is the answer and the example *supports* it!

Comment: If I say 'every boy and girl' then it means every boy and every girl but when I say 'every boy and girls,' it is not to say every girl, but the 'every' is just particular with the boy. Also 'every girls' is incorrect.That's a nice thing to learn.

Answer (score 0):

An important point for use of *every*:

> If I say 'every boy and girl' then it means every boy and every girl but when I say 'every boy and girls,' it is not to say every girl, but the 'every' is just particular with the boy. Also 'every girls' is incorrect.That's a nice thing to learn.