# Each day vs. every day

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "each day" and "every day"?

For example:

> We talk **every** day.
>
> We talk **each** day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Every" vs "each" usage.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113614/every-vs-each-usage) Also, [Use of each and every,](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42736/use-of-each-and-every) and [“every” vs “each”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94878/every-vs-each), among others.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, either would work, with about the same sense. The word "every" puts all days in the same class. The word "each" focuses on the individual days, but the meaning is the same. One can even use the words together redundantly, for emphasis or style:
"We talk each and every day."